# Tags in Onenote

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote, onenote-api

I am syncing OneNote notebooks into my application using MS graph API. Onenote has few tags like To-Do, Important, Question etc. When I fetch html content for particular page these tags comes as data-tag like in -

```
<p lang="en-US" data-tag="important" style="margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt"><span lang="en-GB">Abc</p>
```

How can I replace these tags with the icon with which they are represented in OneNote UI. If I think to skip these tags the notes look very weird.

What is the way to extract this data ?

Comment: Why do you have to render the OneNote page? Why not simply redirect to OneNote?

Comment: My application syncs down the onenote pages to my system and then it will become part of my system so I don't want to redirect

Answer (score 1):

Where are you trying to render this content? Or are you trying to send it back to the OneNote API?

Since this data-tag is a custom attribute, you would need your own custom code to render it on a web page for example.

Comment: @Manjusha- I am trying to render it as HTML in my webapplication. How do I get icon or image associated with this tag ? Like for getting resources we have API something similar to that is there for note tags

Comment: Any clue of how we can render the data-tags through custom code handling since I am not able to get value icon associated with this tag

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to
    1. Get the images associated with each tag - you can use the link below for the full list
    2. Make the API call
    3. Write code that replaces each data tag with the proper

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt159148.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response. From where I can get image associated with this tag. I am not clear about API call for that.Can you please share that API with me please

Comment: The images aren't publicly available, though if I were you, I'd download them from the onenote web client.

Comment: Does Microsoft policy allows this ?

Comment: And what about custom tags in that case

Comment: @Pooja Dhannawat "Custom tags are not supported [by the API]" : [Use note tags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-note-tags) :( But when will they be? (And yes, there is a long-standing and well-supported uservoice request.)